# Is this group representation a finite group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know the question is trivial, but I usually don't work in group theory.

Let $p$ be constant integer number, let $A_n$ be the group generated by  $s$ and $r$ such that $s^p=r^n=1$ and $sr=r^{-1}s$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. That is $A_n$ has the following group presentation:

$$A_n = \left<s,r| s^p=r^n=1,sr=r^{-1}s \right>.$$

Is $A_n$ a **finite group** of order $pn$?

Comment: Yes, each element can be written as $r^ks^l$ for some integers $k,l$, and this representation is unique.

Comment: Thank you, this group seems like generalization to dihedral and dicyclic groups.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same, for dyhedral at least, as I don't know about dicyclic groups.

Comment: From here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group; the dicyclic group has the following presentation :$ \left<s,r|s^4=r^{2n}=1,sr=r^{−1}s\right>$

Comment: Okay, so my comment was wrong, as Derek's answer implies. I'll have to think about where I made a mistake.

Comment: @StefanHamcke : if $p$ is odd then $r^2 = rs^pr = rr^{-1}s^p = 1$

Comment: @mercio: Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a finite group, but its order is not always $pn$. If $p$ is even then the order is $pn$, whereas if $p$ is odd, then the order is $p$ when $n$ is odd and $2p$ when $n$ is even. There is no need to assume that $n \ge p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, doesn't this group seems like  generalization to dihedral and dicyclic groups??

Comment: @Stefan But you didn't make any attempt to justify your assertion. It is easy to see that your map is surjective, but it is not injective when $p$ is odd.

Comment: Right, because if $p$ is odd, then $r^2=rs^pr=rr^{-1}s^p=1$. I see that now. I had not thought about this possibility, so I couldn't find my mistake. Sorry for that.